# How to set checkbox checked when its value is true

Tags: java, jsp

The problem I'm now encourting is that my checkbox isnt being checked when my value returns a value "true".
May I know how I am able to set the checkbox is checked if its true and unchecked if its false.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="s1syslog_enabled" id="s1syslog_enabled" value="${requestScope.data}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
value="${requestScope.data?'checked':''}"
```

Comment: it is still unchecked. The value of true/false is taken from a JSON file fyi

Comment: So, it‘s probably a String of value „true“? Or is it really a boolean true?

Comment: It is a boolean true

Comment: Even when I tick the checkbox, it returns a value "false"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

use checked = "checked" based on your condition

Comment: Sorry but how does this work? where do i insert this

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="s1syslog_enabled" id="s1syslog_enabled" checked = "checked" value="${requestScope.data}">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).